# NMEA checksum calculation calculation

Tags: c, algorithm, gps, checksum, nmea

I am trying to find checksum for NMEA sentence which is already calculated by GPS.

```
char GPRMCBuf[POS_BUFFER] = {0xA0, 0xA2, 0x00, 0x48, 0xDD, 
     0x24, 0x47, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x35, 
     0x30, 0x35, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2C, 
     0x41, 0x2C, 0x34, 0x31, 0x32, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x37, 0x39, 
     0x37, 0x37, 0x2C, 0x4E, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32, 0x31, 
     0x30, 0x2E, 0x39, 0x36, 0x36, 0x37, 0x2C, 0x45, 0x2C, 
     0x31, 0x2E, 0x35, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x35, 0x38, 0x2E, 0x32, 
     0x39, 0x2C, 0x32, 0x33, 0x30, 0x37, 0x31, 0x35, 0x2C, 
     0x2C, 0x2C, 0x41, 0x2A, 0x35, 0x38, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0F, 
     0x05, 0xB0, 0xB3};
```

hear last 3rd and 4th char are checksum that is 0F05
but we want to correct algorithm. Our algorithm which we used is as follows

```
Index = first,
checkSum = 0,
while index < msgLen,
checkSum = checkSum + message[index],
checkSum = checkSum AND (2^15-1).
increment index.
```

code we have written is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned short chk;

    char test[]={ 0x47, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x2C, 0x31, 
            0x35, 0x30, 0x35, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x30, 
            0x30, 0x2C, 0x41, 0x2C, 0x34, 0x31, 0x32, 0x31, 
            0x2E, 0x37, 0x39, 0x37, 0x37, 0x2C, 0x4E, 0x2C, 
            0x30, 0x30, 0x32, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x39, 0x36, 
            0x36, 0x37, 0x2C, 0x45, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x35, 
            0x30, 0x2C, 0x35, 0x38, 0x2E, 0x32, 0x39, 0x2C, 
            0x32, 0x33, 0x30, 0x37, 0x31, 0x35, 0x2C, 0x2C, 
            0x2C, 0x41,0x2A, 0x35, 0x38, 0x0D, 0x0A}; 

    chk = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 70; i++)
    {    
        chk = chk + test[i];
        chk = chk & 32767;  
    }
    printf("A=%hu\n", chk);
    return 0;
}
```

problem is that we are getting 3588 but it should be 3845(0F05).

Please help us to solve this algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried to google? https://rietman.wordpress.com/2008/09/25/how-to-calculate-the-nmea-checksum/

Comment: Following @EugeneSh. although I tried the correct XOR method (not your addition) between `'$'` and `'*'` (you should have stopped before the `'*'`), I can't get the right checksum. Note, it is supposed to be an 8 bit checksum split into two nibbles, not the 15 bit checksum you have used. I see too that your NMEA message has been bulked up by some other protocol. Maybe it changed the checksum method too, or maybe it got it wrong.

Answer (score 9):

You've made a good attempt, but you've got a few things wrong.

Each command is self-contained, starts with a `$` symbol and ends with a carriage return/line feed combination. The checksum, when present, is at the end of the message and preceded by an asterisk `*`. You'll also see that the checksum is an XOR of all bytes between the `$` and the `*`, and the checksum, in hexadecimal, follows the `*` in ASCII format.

Your input data also has some noise at the beginning and end, which you need to discard. Let me annotate your input:

```
char GPRMCBuf[POS_BUFFER] = {
    0xA0, 0xA2, 0x00, 0x48, 0xDD, // these bytes are not part of the message
     
    0x24, // this is the '$' character, so this is the message start byte

    // checksum calculation starts with the next byte (0x47)
    0x47, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4D, 0x43, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x35,        // GPRMC,15
    0x30, 0x35, 0x32, 0x30, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2C,  // 0520.000,
    0x41, 0x2C, 0x34, 0x31, 0x32, 0x31, 0x2E, 0x37, 0x39,  // A,4121.79
    0x37, 0x37, 0x2C, 0x4E, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x30, 0x32, 0x31,  // 77,N,0021
    0x30, 0x2E, 0x39, 0x36, 0x36, 0x37, 0x2C, 0x45, 0x2C,  // 0.9667,E,
    0x31, 0x2E, 0x35, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x35, 0x38, 0x2E, 0x32,  // 1.50,58.2
    0x39, 0x2C, 0x32, 0x33, 0x30, 0x37, 0x31, 0x35, 0x2C,  // 9,230715,
    0x2C, 0x2C, 0x41,                                      // ,,A
    // checksum calculation ends here

    0x2A,       // The '*' character, i.e. message/checksum delimiter
    0x35, 0x38, // The checksum, '5' and '8', so the checksum is 0x58
    0x0D, 0x0A, // The CR/LF line terminator
     
    0x0F, 0x05, 0xB0, 0xB3 // these bytes are not part of the message
};
```

So, the checksum calculation is:

```
chk = 0;
chk = chk ^ 0x47; // chk = 0x47
chk = chk ^ 0x50; // chk = 0x17
chk = chk ^ 0x52; // chk = 0x45
...
chk = chk ^ 0x41; // chk = 0x58
```

Note that you'll end up with `0x58`, which is in the message as `0x35 0x38`. So once you've correctly framed the message and adjusted the for loop to iterate over the checksummed bytes, the loop body simply becomes:

```
chk ^= test[i];
```

After the loop you then need to either convert the two nibbles of `chk` into ASCII and compare with the signalled checksum, or convert the signalled checksum to a binary value and compare with `chk`.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this function, in the past, to calculate a NMEA checksum
for the purpose of comparing with the checksum in the NMEA message.

```
int calc_NMEA_Checksum( char *buf, int cnt )
{
    char Character;
    int Checksum = 0;
    int i;              // loop counter



    //foreach(char Character in sentence)
    for (i=0;i<cnt;++i)
    {
        Character = buf[i];
        switch(Character)
        {
            case '$':
                // Ignore the dollar sign
                break;
            case '*':
                // Stop processing before the asterisk
                i = cnt;
                continue;
            default:
                // Is this the first value for the checksum?
                if (Checksum == 0)
                {
                    // Yes. Set the checksum to the value
                    Checksum = Character;
                }
                else
                {
                    // No. XOR the checksum with this character's value
                    Checksum = Checksum ^ Character;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    // Return the checksum
    return (Checksum);

} // calc_NEMA_Checksum()
```

after this calculation, extract the two byte checksum from the NMEA message, re-format that 2 byte hex value into a 1byte value, then compare with the above calculated value

Comment: FYI: the `if (Checksum == 0)` check is superfluous, because `(0 ^ x === x)`

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers are saying, you have exclude the '$' and '*' in the checksum calculation. You could use the function from the C library [libnmea](https://github.com/jacketizer/libnmea.git):

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define NMEA_END_CHAR_1 '\n'
#define NMEA_MAX_LENGTH 70

uint8_t
nmea_get_checksum(const char *sentence)
{
    const char *n = sentence + 1; // Plus one, skip '$'
    uint8_t chk = 0;

    /* While current char isn't '*' or sentence ending (newline) */
    while ('*' != *n && NMEA_END_CHAR_1 != *n) {
        if ('\0' == *n || n - sentence > NMEA_MAX_LENGTH) {
            /* Sentence too long or short */
            return 0;
        }
        chk ^= (uint8_t) *n;
        n++;
    }

    return chk;
}
```

Then call the function with your sentence string as argument:

```
uint8_t chk = nmea_get_checksum(GPRMCBuf);
```